# Does the Intergral Test require the integrand to converge to zero to be applicable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Is there an error in the following statement of the Integral Test (from David Brannan's Mathematical Analysis)?

[image]

The author requires the integrand (equivalently, the general term of the series) to converge to zero for the test to be applied. Is this correct? For if the integrand converges to zero, then the series converges, so there is no need to apply the Integral Test, is there?

Comment: I guess no, the integrand converges doesn't imply summation of integrand converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ADD** The condition that $a_n\not \to 0$ is **sufficient** for a sequence $a_n$ to fail to have a sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$
That is, if $a_n\not\to 0$ then $\sum a_n$ fails to exists.

This implies, by contrapositiveness, that the condition $a_n\to 0$ is **necessary** for the sequence to have a sum, but it is not **sufficient**. That is, if $\sum a_n$ exists, then $a_n\to 0$.

However, there is a canonical example where we see how this fails:

$$\frac 1 n\to 0\text{ however } \sum \frac 1 n $$ fails to exist.

---

Observe that because $f$ is positive and decreasing

$$\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)\leq \int_1^n f \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)$$

From the first side of the above, and assuming  $$\int_1^n f $$ is bounded above by some number $R$, we get that $$\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)\leq R$$ for each $n$.

Since $f$ is positive, the series is monotone **increasing**, so that by the monotone convergence theorem, the result follows.

On the other hand, the rightmost inequality implies that if $$ \int_1^n f $$ diverges, so does $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)$$

by direct comparison.

Comment: Does the word "contrapositiveness" even exist? Came in handy, but I think I just invented it.

Comment: There are surprisingly plenty of english words (or word forms) that haven't been officially "invented" that should be and are probably in wide private usage anyway.:)  Thanks for helping me sort out the confusion. My new question then, is, why have that stipulation? If $f$ *doesn't* converge to zero, then the series automatically diverges, yes, but the Integral Test would still be applicable (if we insisted to use it), so isn't the stipulation unnecessarily restrictive of the theorem's sphere of applicability?

Comment: I.e. my original question  in the title still stands: Does the integral test **require** the integrand to converge to zero to be *applicable*?

Comment: @Ryan If the integrand doesn't converge to zero, you already know the sequence diverges, so why bother applying the test?

Comment: @Ryan The theorem is perfect as it stands. The stipulation that $f\to 0$ *is needed*, since else the theorem *wouldn't be true*. Note that if $f$ didn't tend to $0$; the hypothesis that $\int_1^n f$ is bounded would be utterly impossible, for instance. On the other hand, the "divergence" criterion in this theorem is a "finer" test than $a_n\not\to 0$. We get past that, i.e. assume it is true, and show that even if that is true, the $f$ failing to be integrable is all we need to show divergence.

Comment: "Note that if f didn't tend to 0; the hypothesis that ∫n1f is bounded would be utterly impossible" Which is precisely why the theorem (*minus* the stipulation that $f$ converges to zero) (correctly) implies that such a series is divergent! So how is the theorem untrue in this regard?

Comment: @Ryan But that part of the theorem asserts convergence, not divergence! Read carefully. The theorem enunciates that $a_n\to 0$ because it is part of its hypothesis. The first part, which asserts convergence needs this (because else it would make no sense) and the second part which asserts divergence assumes this because else divergence would already be true, and one wouldn't need the theorem at all.

Comment: If $f$ did $not$ converge to zero, then Part (a)'s hypthesis is false, so its conclusion doesn't hold. At the same time, part (b)'s hypothesis would be true, so its conclusion (that the series diverges) is true.  In short, the Integral Test *does* apply even when $f$ does not converge to zero! (Though we wouldn't need to use the integral test since the "non-null test" already immediately tells us that the series diverges. But this is beside the point.)

Answer (score 1):

This may help: Note that the convergence test states that IF a series converges, THEN the limit of $f(n)$/"the integrand" is $zero$.

The converse does not necessarily follow.

That is, if the $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0,\;$ we cannot conclude that the series converges. We don't know. Recall the example of $f(n) = \large\frac 1n.\;$ It's limit as $n\to \infty$ is $0$, but the series $\sum_{n^\infty} f(n)$ does not converge.

It's cases like this when the integral test comes in handy.

Indeed, the condition that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$ must be met for the integral test to apply.